# What Game engines and  game libraries are available for ubuntu?

Tags: application-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What 2D/3D engines and game SDKs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34200/what-2d-3d-engines-and-game-sdks-are-available)

What game engines and game libraries are available for ubuntu?  And how to install its latest version