# Game designing app 3d

Tags: games, design, ps3

I'm new to Ubuntu and I’m looking for a free software studio so i can make an indie game for PS4/3. I am just throwing around ideas on paper but i want to see if they can work.

Comment: Seems off topic to me. Create games for the PS4/PS3 you do with a PS3 or PS4 and the official SDK. And are you already an official developer? The Unity engine costs 1500 USD.

Comment: Oh and see: http://www.playstation.com/en-us/develop/ if you are American.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/)

This is one of the most professional Open Source 3D engines available. It is a bit difficult to set up, but it is rather powerful. The standard API is in C++ but there are bindings for several other languages.

More info at the [OGRE Wiki](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Home).

[Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/)

Python & C++ interface. Quite a tool. This tool has a very active IRC community.

Answer copied from here:

- [What 2D/3D engines and game SDKs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34200/what-2d-3d-engines-and-game-sdks-are-available/34246#34246)

Comment: How does this work in relation to a PS3, PS4 game?

Comment: Well, there is no official SDK for PS consoles yet for Linux, as far as I can tell. I was just showing the other "alternatives"

Comment: There never will.